# How can we set nodetool and cqlsh to be run from anywhere and by any user on linux server

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, nodetool

I am trying to setup environment variables so that any user on a particular server can run commands like nodetool or cqlsh from any where in linux file system . The effort to traverse to bin directory everytime should be saved .
How can we achieve this ? My DSE 4.8 is a tarball install .

Comment: Just append the $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin to $PATH 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/24937/how-do-i-set-path-variables-for-all-users-on-a-server

Answer (score 0):

- Nodetool is usually available to any user that has execution privileges in your linux boxes
- For cqlsh, you can set any configuration inside the [cqlshrc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlshrc.html) file (usually found in $HOME/.cassandra/cqlshrc; we have used to enable client-node encryption but has more configurable options

Answer (score 0):

To setup environment variable just follow some steps from root user:

```
# vi /etc/profile.d/cassandra.sh
```

Add the following lines to the `cassandra.sh` file-

```
export CASSANDRA_HOME=/opt/apache-cassandra-3.0.8
export CASSANDRA_CONF_DIR=/opt/apache-cassandra-3.0.8/conf
```

Here `/opt/` is my directory, where I've extracted my `apache-cassandra-3.0.8-bin.tar.gz` tarball.

After adding those lines to `cassandra.sh`, save and exit. Then-

```
# source /etc/profile.d/cassandra.sh
```