# setting java_home and path environmental variables in linux

Tags: java, linux, cassandra

I downloaded java-8 and amd combined package for working with Cassandra in linux. When I run cassandra, it is showing as-
***Unable to find java executable. Check JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.***

How to correctly set those variables?

Answer (score 3):

Open `~/.bashrc` and add

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path to your java>
export PATH=<path to your java>:$PATH
```

with the path where your java is and then reopen terminal or execute `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: what do java_home and path variables exactly resemble and how should we set them?

Comment: you set them like i said, these are environment variables that resemble paths where programs will try to find your java.

Comment: permissions denied.. is there any other option?

Comment: yes, execute it in your terminal, but you will need to execute it every time you reopen terminal (changing `.bashrc` does it instead of you)

Answer (score 2):

Correct solution is:

- Open ~/.bashrc file
- Add to this file 2 lines as below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=Path_to_Java_installation_folder
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

in the bottom.

Logoff and login again, then check the result.

Answer (score 2):

To setup environment variable just follow some steps from root user:

```
# vi /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

Add the following lines to the `java.sh` file-

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

After adding those lines to `java.sh`, save and exit. Then-

```
# source /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

For cassandra environment variable setup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39940053/4610541

Comment: Thanks.... helped me

Answer (score 1):

sudo vim /etc/profile

add at the last sucu as:
export JAVA_HOME=/home/software/jdk1.8.0_71

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code to /etc/profile file

```
JAVA_HOME=<Path to JDK folder>
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

You can refer to this article [Install JDK in ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)